# html5 & bootstrap modal popup - how to confirm before cancel?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this cancel button, which when clicked I would like to display a confirmation prompt before closing the modal popup window;

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel" />
```

As you can see, I am using the data-dismiss property to close the modal popup.
However if the user has started entering data in the form, I would like to prompt the user to confirm that they want to leave without making changes.
I could capture the click event in jquery, but I would then have to close the popup myself and not use data-dismiss.
So what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of doing it is exactly how you described. Remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute and instead close it yourself ([using Bootstraps 'hide' method](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) (scroll down to 'methods')) if they confirm they want to exit and lose changes, like this.

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel. You will lose your unsaved changes')){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
}
```